# Easy driving, direct route from Syracuse, NY, to Lake Placid?

Tags: usa, routes, new-york-state, syracuse

I would like a route where I won't have to keep stopping to ask for directions, as happened to me last year with the standard Rte 81 Rte 3 approach. Also, I don't like extremely twisty-turny routes. I'd like to find a route that is reasonably quick and fairly easy driving.

I am considering this alternate route: I-90, NY-365, NY-8. Recommendations?

Comment: Welcome! Just a heads up - phrases like 'best' and 'opinions' tend to be red alerts on travel.se as the [help] forbids soliciting subjective viewpoints.  It might be best to reword it for 'least twisty-turny route' or 'fastest route' or whatever objective measurement you're after, or it's likely to get closed as opinion-based :/

Comment: @MarkMayo - Heeded your helpful advice and did some editing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a navigator in the car or a Smartphone where you can launch [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Syracuse,+NY/Lake+Placid,+NY/@43.6258099,-75.3289641,10z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x89d9f39bbf979a0d:0xd50ce2d7ad9545!2m2!1d-76.1474244!2d43.0481221!1m5!1m1!1s0x4ccae263be62315b:0x282ca3e6dd25d3c2!2m2!1d-73.9798713!2d44.2794911), [Waze](https://www.waze.com/), and a whole bunch of other possible software, then consider this:

The clearest way to get to Lake Placid is from I-87, where you take an exit toward Lake Placid which would be NY-73 and stay on it until you hit downtown Lake Placid.

Problem with that route is that it is taking you a long way around the Adirondacks from Syracuse to Albany and then north toward Lake Placid but you don't have to drive through back woods of Adirondacks to get there.